# Collision/overlap detection of circles in a d3 transition

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, collision-detection, transition

I'm using d3 to animate a route (path) on a map. When the route reaches a point along the route I'd like to popup some information.

Most of my code is based on the following example. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868.  I'm really just trying to determine if there is a way to detect when the transitioning circle collides or overlaps any of the stationary circles in this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [detect collision](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298) in your tween function. Define a `collide` function to be called from inside the tween function as follows:

```
function collide(node){
    var trans = d3.transform(d3.select(node).attr("transform")).translate,
      x1 = trans[0],
      x2 = trans[0] + (+d3.select(node).attr("r")),
      y1 = trans[1],
      y2 = trans[1] + (+d3.select(node).attr("r"));

  var colliding = false;
  points.each(function(d,i){
    var ntrans = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")).translate,
      nx1 = ntrans[0],
      nx2 = ntrans[0] + (+d3.select(this).attr("r")),
      ny1 = ntrans[1],
      ny2 = ntrans[1] + (+d3.select(this).attr("r"));


      if(!(x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1))
        colliding=true;
  })

  return colliding;
}
```

Where `points` are the stationary points, and `node` is the transitioning element. What `collide` does is check whether `node` *overlaps* with any of the points (as shown in [collision detection example here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298)).

Because we need the `node` to be passed to the tween function, we replace `attrTween` used in Mike's example, with `tween`:

```
circle.transition()
      .duration(10000)
      .tween("attr", translateAlong(path.node()))
      .each("end", transition);
```

Finally, the tween function calling our `collide`:

```
function translateAlong(path) {
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  return function(d, i, a) {
    return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);

      d3.select(this).attr("transform","translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")");

      if(collide(this))
        d3.select(this).style("fill", "red")
       else
        d3.select(this).style("fill", "steelblue")
    };
  };
}
```

See the [full demo here](http://bl.ocks.org/ahmohamed/c1804b03b71d8a17bd37)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just check how "close" the transitioning circle is to the other points.

```
var pop = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .style("position","absolute")
    .style("top",0)
    .style("left",0)
    .style("display", "none")
    .style("background", "yellow")
    .style("border", "1px solid black");

// Returns an attrTween for translating along the specified path element.
function translateAlong(path) {
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  var epsilon = 5;
  return function(d, i, a) {
    return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      points.forEach(function(d,i){
        if ((Math.abs(d[0] - p.x) < epsilon) && 
            (Math.abs(d[1] - p.y) < epsilon)){
          pop.style("left",d[0]+"px")
            .style("top",d[1]+20+"px")
            .style("display","block")
            .html(d);
          return false;
        }
      })
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    };
  };
}
```

The faster the circle moves the greater your epsilon will need to be.

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SV5ICuXAUYdKz3YpaorU?p=info).

[image]